# convert shapefile to polygon

Tags: r, polygon, shapefile

I have a shapefile that is the outline of a lake that I will be mapping with in R. I load in the shapefile with:

```
Lake <- readOGR("File directory", "Lake")
```

I need this shapefile to be a Polygon, not a SpatialPolygon or SpatialPolygonDataFrame.

```
str(Lake)
Formal class 'SpatialPolygons' [package "sp"] with 4 slots
..@ polygons   :List of 1
.. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
.. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 3
.. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] -84.7 39.6
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 0.000255
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi FALSE
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int 1
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:1333, 1:2] -84.8 -84.8 -84.8 -84.8 
.. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] -84.8 39.6
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 7.39e-07
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi TRUE
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int -1
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:40, 1:2] -84.8 -84.8 -84.8 -84.8 
.. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] -84.8 39.6
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 3.21e-06
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi TRUE
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int -1
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:65, 1:2] -84.8 -84.8 -84.8 -84.8  
.. .. .. ..@ plotOrder: int [1:3] 1 3 2
.. .. .. ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] -84.7 39.6
.. .. .. ..@ ID       : chr "0"
.. .. .. ..@ area     : num 0.000255
..@ plotOrder  : int 1
..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] -84.8 39.6 -84.7 39.6
.. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
.. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
.. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84   
+towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Using RGeostats package, to perform geostatistical analyses, I have to be working with a polygon, not any other object type. This is because I have to select the area encompassing the entire lake to run further analysis on. Object db.data stores fish densities at specific lat/lon points.

```
db.data=db.polygon(db.data, Lake)
The input object is of type ' SpatialPolygons '. It should be of type '   
polygon '
The function is interrupted
Error: Invalid object type
```

How do I get my shapefile to be read as a polygon?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the @polygons object to a new object.

Like so:

```
LakePolygons<-Lake@polygons
```

Comment: That turns it into a list

    db.data=db.polygon(db.data, LakePolygons)
    The input object is of type ' list '. It should be of type ' polygon '
    The function is interrupted
    Error: Invalid object type

Comment: Can you try either of these:

     Lake$polygons
     Lake@polygons$polygons